# How to detect android.permission.USE_SIP

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, sip-server, voip-android

Now I have a serious problem with my manifest. I don't know why even after had `android.permission.USE_SIP` in manifest, this is not recognized. I use this code to detect.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_SIP)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "la permission est donnée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "la permission est abscente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And it is the clause else that is run. Please help me to debug this, thank you.

This is a part of my logcat.

```
Process: com.example.boris.voipapp, PID: 19509
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10105 nor current process has android.permission.USE_SIP.
    at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1600)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1632)
```

Comment: A more appropriated stackexchange sub is https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a part of code that that resolve the problem

```js
/** initialisation du SIP*/
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_SIP)
               == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
       }else{
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.USE_SIP}, 0);
       }
```